# Why the code executes twice whenever first run after launching Maya?

Tags: python, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def aaa():
    blah... blah...

aaa()
```

## saved this code as aaa.py and placed it right folder and launched Maya and run the code by

```
import aaa
reload(aaa)
```

And it executes twice when the first run. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

> And it executes twice when the first run.

Because calling `import aaa`, will execute all the code in `aaa`, and thus it will call the `aaa()` function. then calling `reload(aaa)` will re-import `aaa`, so it will run all of the code in it again.

> How can I prevent that?

Just remove the `reload(aaa)`, I really don't see why you have it there in the first place, it's very seldom needed.

---

I don't also understand why you have you're code organized like that in the first place. You should almost certainly have them be like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def aaa():
    blah... blah...
```

```
from aaa import aaa

aaa()
```

Comment: Because without reload(), it will execute code only the first time. From the second run, you need reload(), right?

Comment: No, you don't understand. Of course your code will run twice if you place a function call in a module which you first `import` and then `reload`.